# QGIS upgrade from 1.8 to 2.12: Vector layers are not displayed

Tags: vector, qgis-2.12

I just updated my very outdated version of QGIS. I was running 1.8 and thought the new version would work out a couple kinks that had developed. Well, now I can't even figure out how to make my vector data files appear after I add the layers.

The vector files are in the layers panel but nothing on the screen. Everything is projected and I try to zoom to layer and nothing! I'm just trying to add .csv files of camera trap locations and other files with gps points. Is there some simple fix like a setting I have to activate?

Comment: You may have zero features in your layer. Have you checked the attribute table of your layers? Is it empty?

Comment: Your problem description is a bit unclear. Do you have by chance a screenshot of the CSV dialog? How do you add the CSV? Do you use the right [command (manual link)](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/supported_data.html#delimited-text-files)?